# Can we make it easier to see a deleted user's deleted posts?

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-tools, deleted-posts, deleted-accounts

Moderators can see a list of posts from a deleted user, which is very useful for cleaning up two kinds of problems:

- rage-quits, where we might want to undelete some of those
- users with a pattern of abusive content, where we  might want to delete more posts

The moderator view provides the information we need, but I find it a little hard to manage for prolific users.  We currently get a list of posts with either "yes" or "no" to indicate deletion; can we supplement this?  I can think of two options:

- Style the posts in the list with the pink "deleted" background for the ones that are.  This is consistent with other places in the UI where posts or comments are deleted but visible to moderators.
- Enable the table to be sorted on that column.

I think the first option is easier and is also the interface I would prefer, but I'm open to anything that makes it easier to review this information for a user with dozens of posts (or more).

I know I can visually scan or Ctrl-F my way through the page.  The current page isn't *broken*; it's just harder to use than I'd like and I *think* the styling option isn't hard, so I'm asking.